# Adjusting CollectionView Cells to centre for different iphone sizes

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I'm trying to centre my collectionView cells in iOS. I have content inset for left & right as:

```
([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width - 80)/2
```

This allows the first cell and last cell to stop in the centre of the screen.

What I'm trying to achieve with the above is when the view loads, I want the middle cell to be in the centre of the view. If there are cells 1,2,3,4,5. I want to load the view with 3 in the middle.

So I'm trying to accomplish it with contentOffset. However, I'm having a hard time trying to find the relations of the cells, inset and offset.

My cells are 80 wide and margins are 10.

The collection view will only have 1 row.

EDIT:

[View post on imgur.com](//imgur.com/zbFCW75)

The attached image is what I want to accomplish. Sorry if my initial description wasn't as clear. The collectionView will only have 1 row but wide cells.

Updated Code:

```
- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section{
 return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width - 80)/2, 0, ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width - 80)/2);
}
```

Cell 1 & 5 will be out of bounds and will only be seen when user scrolls horizontally.

|_1__| |_2__| |_3__||_4__| |_5__|

UPDATE: What I want to do is for the collectionView to scroll to the middle cell and centre that cell on the screen.

Comment: where are you using `([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width - 80)/2` code? show full method.

Answer (score 0):

Setup collection cell layout:

```
@property(nonatomic, strong)UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.collectionView registerClass:[CellClass class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier"];
    self.collectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    // Configure layout
    self.flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    [self.flowLayout setItemSize:CGSizeMake((30*screenWidth)/100, desiredHeight)];
    [self.flowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];
    self.flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 8.0f;//set desired item spacing
    [self.collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:self.flowLayout];
}
```

To scroll to desired cell:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated 
{
    //get the item index to scroll to
    NSInteger focusItem = floor(array.count/2);//this may cause some error, debug yourself  

    NSIndexPath *indexPath= [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:focusItem  inSection:0];
    [self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredHorizontally animated:NO];
}
```

Comment: I've added a image to the question. Please have a look. Thanks

Comment: I saw image , where the 1st and 5th items are to be placed? Above and below 3 elements with full width?

Comment: So the items are in order in 1 row. Cell 3 will be in the middle and each cell has 10px of margin in between.

Comment: Okkkkkkk....you should have posted it earlier. That mean you want to show middle three elements of the array?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101047/discussion-between-eric-chuang-and-the-ub).

Answer (score 0):

Use this flowlayout for your collectionview, it will adjust your collectionview as howmany rows you want to show on screen

```
//initial values
leftMargin = 5;
rightMargin = 5;
lineSpacing = 0;
cellSpacing = 0;
topSpacing = 0;
numberOfCellInRow = 3;

 #pragma mark - CollectionView FlowLayout
-(UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)flowLayout{

if(!_flowLayout){

    _flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    [_flowLayout setSectionInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(topSpacing, leftMargin, 0, rightMargin)];
    [_flowLayout setMinimumInteritemSpacing:cellSpacing];
    [_flowLayout setMinimumLineSpacing:lineSpacing];
    [_flowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];

    CGSize screenSize = self.view.frame.size;
    CGFloat cellWidth = (screenSize.width - ((leftMargin + rightMargin) + ((numberOfCellInRow -1)*cellSpacing)))/numberOfCellInRow;
    CGFloat cellHeight = // height of cell here;
    [_flowLayout setItemSize:CGSizeMake(cellWidth, cellHeight)];
  }

  return _flowLayout;
}

//Set CollectionView Layout
[self.collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:self.flowLayout];

 -(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  CGSize rect = self.collectionView.frame.size;
  rect.width = rect.width / 3;

   return rect;
 }
```

Comment: I think this only sets the layout of the collectionView. What I want to do is for the collectionView to scroll to the middle cell and centre that cell on the screen.

Comment: Please refer my edited answer. It will always display your cells in center after scrolling collectionview.
Assumption: your collectionview width is equal to screen width

Comment: Your solution only adjust the sizing of the cells as opposed to position. What I'm trying to do is to position the middle cell in the centre of the collectionView. My collectionView scrolls from left to right and items will go out of bounds.